# 32 bit/64 bit Compiling and Application Speed

Tags: performance, 64-bit, 32-bit

I just got a new 64 bit computer and I am still trying to understand the differences between 32 bit and 64 bit. I understand that applications built using 64-bit dependencies can only run on a 64 bit, but applications built with 32-bit dependencies can run on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

However, is there any other differences? I know some programs have two different windows versions you can download, one for 64 bit and one for 32 bit. Why do they provide the two different types? Is there a speed increase for compiling a program with 64 bit dependencies for a program to run on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Porting code to 64-bit systems. The pros and cons - http://www.viva64.com/en/l/0003/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides from speed some programs do not have a choice. They need to match the bitness of the host operating system exactly.

A good example is TortoiseSVN which installs a shell extension. Shell extensions are DLLs loaded into other processes. So TortoiseSVN must provide a 64 bit DLL on x64 system if it wants to provide a shell extension.

Drivers are a second example of this.

When it comes to speed there is a difference of course. It depends very much on what the program does. If a program does not require high performance providing an x64 executable does not help and is a waste of time for both developers just as for users.

Here is what causes a performance difference for the case 32 bit on 64 bit OS:

1. Higher kernel-call cost because of the mode switch
2. More registers, higher code size: For calculation intensive programs this works vastly in favor of native 64 bit apps. For other types of app, or for business style web applications the bigger code and pointer sizes might cause a net loss (so 64 bit slower than 32 bit!)
3. Access to more than 3GB of memory. This obviously comes into play rarely as of 2012. Think of databases, Photoshop, ...

Comment: Thank you, that answered by question quite well.

Comment: This answer is true on Windows, but not true on OSX. 32 bit apps will run fine on 64 bit OSX, and there are significant benefits to having every app be 64 bit (specifically, the 32 bit dyld shared cache will not be loaded, saving >100MB of IO and memory)

Comment: Plus Apple revamped the Objective-C runtime when they made it 64 bits, adding some functionality that wouldn't have been feasible if they had had to worry about 32-bit backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The speed increase depends on what the application does, as usr said. But fundamentally a 64-bit CPU is able to process twice as much data as a 32-bit one in the same amount of time; but the machine instructions to do so are specific to the 64-bit processor, so existing native programs have to be recompiled (at the very least) to show the benefit.

In the case of x86_64, memory pointers are also now 64 bits wide instead of 32, meaning much more memory can be addressed by programs. However, the code takes up roughly twice as much space in disk and on memory; if you're on a 64-bit system that's starved for memory, swapping can potentially be a lot worse.

Comment: While this is true, it's very misleading. They're processing twice as many bits, but not twice as many values. Operations will be (everything else being equal) the same speed up until the point where individual integers require more than 32 bits to represent, then the 32 bit machine will slow down dramatically and the 64 bit one won't.

Comment: (Of course, you can also do things like process two or more 32 bit numbers at the same time, but that's not related to 64 bit processors. That's related to MMX/SSE[n]/Altivec)

Comment: I was thinking more of things like copying more than 32 bits of memory. But now that I think about it, that's probably done with DMA or something; I'm not sure how bus width affects that these days.

Comment: Bus width and cacheline size are (at least somewhat) independent of maximum integer width and pointer width. It is totally true though that you can do things like check 8 bytes against a mask at the same time vs 4 with a 32 bit processor (by using a 64 bit mask value that's the 8 bit mask repeated 8 times). So there's definitely wins to be had.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will roughly the same for most languages.

The main reason to go for 64 bit is the addressable memory. A32 bit process has only access to 2 GB of data, but a 64 bit process can access 18 quintillion Bytes (that is way more than the amount of RAM you can put in your machine).